# After 16.04 installation: hang at blank purple screen

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I just installed 16.04 on a new box (along side Windows 10). When I boot into Ubuntu the system hangs at a blank purple screen. If I boot into Recovery Mode and select "Resume" the system boots to a low resolution login screen. I can log in. If I immediately reboot to try logging in normally again the same hang occurs.

The only odd thing about this machine is that it has a GTX 1080 ti Nvidia card. I haven't installed any Nvidia drivers yet. Should I? If so, is [this](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/24/nvidia-367-44-support-titan-x-pascal-gtx-1060/) really the right way to install the Nvidia drivers?

I'm not sure how to proceed and I don't want to make things worse. TIA

Comment: The easiest way to install the driver is to run `sudo apt install nvidia-375`, then reboot and disable Secure Boot in BIOS. That's easy.

Comment: Why would I install v375 when v384.59 is stable and available? And I thought that going the ppa route was supposed to make future driver upgrades easier.

Comment: It's because the 375 driver is in Ubuntu repos. The PPA is unofficial. The 375 is LTS. Later you can install any driver you like. The 375.82 has been released this week.